# Configurations from External Projects in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, ide, propertysheet

I am having a problem with Visual Studio 2012, and I am hoping there is a solution to this. I have in my solution 2 projects:  1 project is an ".exe" project, and the other is a ".lib" project.  I have added the lib project as a reference in the exe project, and I have ensured that it is scheduled to be compiled first.  The lib project has a bunch of additional include directories and a bunch of additional dependencies and linked libraries.  The lib project compiles fine.  However, none of the additional include directories or additional library directories or dependencies are being inherited by the exe application.  I was able to resolve this by copying the configurations to the exe project, but that means that if I ever update the lib dependencies, then I need to update it in every project that uses this library (I play to use this library for multiple projects).  This seems like something that there should be a solution for, but I just can't seem to find it.  Has anyone figured out a way to have projects  inherit the configurations of referenced projects, or is there no way around this?  Thanks.

Comment: There generally isn't much overlap in settings between a static library and the projects consuming it.  The static library project needs compiler settings, such as include files for other libraries used in the implementation.  The executable needs linker settings, such as paths to library files, and the public include directory of the library.  Actual names of libraries can be specified using `#pragma comment(lib)`.  Of course, there IS overlap between all the consumers of the library if it is used in many applications, so sharing property sheets is still worthwhile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right, projects don't inherit the properties of other projects they reference.  To solve your problem what you need is a **property sheet**. A property sheet is a collection of Properties (like you set in your Project Properties) separate from a project.  You can apply a single property sheet to many projects.

In your case, the "additional library dependencies" and "additional include directories" will be placed into a property sheet.  That property sheet will be applied to both your `.exe` project and your `.lib` project. When you make changes, you will make them to the property sheet and both projects will see the changes.

Let's go step-by-step through setting up a property sheet to do what you want.

1. Load your solution file with your `.exe` and `.lib` projects. Let's suppose the name of your library is `PowerMath.lib` and your main executable is `SuperCalc.exe`.
2. Find the **Solution Explorer** window in Visual Studio.  This is the sub-window that lists all your projects, and the files inside those projects.  (If you don't have one, click on the View menu and choose the Solution Explorer option to create one.)
3. First, let's take the settings *out* of the Project Properties where you have them set now.  Go to the project properties for the `PowerMath.lib` project (right-click on that project in the Solution Explorer and choose Properties from the context menu).  Find your "additional library dependencies" and "additional include directories" settings that you made, and delete them. (Only delete your changes, not whatever was there before.)  (Also, write your stuff down or copy it somewhere -- it's going to come back in step 10.) When you are done with the `PowerMath.lib` project, repeat the process with the `SuperCalc.exe` project.  Rip it all out so it doesn't interfere with the new approach we're going to take.  Be sure you've done this for all configurations of your projects (Debug and Release, Win32 and x64).
4. Down at the bottom of the Solution Explorer window you will see several tabs, including:  Solution Explorer, Class View, and Property Manager. These may be abbreviated if the window is small.  Click on **Property Manager**.
5. In the Property Manager you'll see two entries: the `PowerMath` and `SuperCalc` project names.  Right-click on the `PowerMath.lib` project, and choose the menu option **Add New Property Sheet**.
6. Choose a good Name that refers to your library.  I would suggest `PowerMath-settings.props`. Then click **Add** to create the property sheet, and automatically attach it to the `PowerMath` .lib project.
7. Back in the Property Manager pane, you see that PowerMath has two elements underneath it: **Debug** and **Release**.  These are the two configurations of your library.  If you "open them up" by clicking on them with the mouse, you'll see that the `PowerMath-settings` property sheet has been attached to both configurations.
8. The `PowerMath-settings` property sheet is listed above a bunch of other property sheets that were already present, which have names like `Core Windows Libraries` and `Unicode Support`.  *All* of the settings in any configuration of your projects come from combining these property sheets! That's how properties work inside Visual Studio -- putting together all the project's property sheets, in order with the first one at the bottom.
9. Double-click on the `PowerMath-settings` property sheet in the list.  This will take you to the familiar Project Properties interface.  Changes made here don't apply to a project or a particular configuration inside that project.  Instead, you're writing the settings only for the property sheet `PowerMath-settings.props`.
10. Now you get to write your **additional library dependencies** and **additional include directories**.  Go to the dialog boxes where you expect to set those things.  In the appropriate fields, click the little down arrow at the right side of the field and pick `Edit...`.
11. In the edit box you will see a blank space where you can write your new settings.  (You'll also see the "inherited values", which are the settings that came from other property sheets.)  Add your stuff and then click OK.
12. When you're done, you'll have a property sheet called `PowerMath-settings.props` that stores the settings needed for all users of the `PowerMath.lib` library.
13. Now go back to the Property Manager window.  Right-click on the `SuperCalc` project instead (this is your .exe).  Choose the menu option **Add Existing Property Sheet**.  Find `PowerMath-settings.props` and select it.
14. Boom, now `SuperCalc.exe` gets all the settings you just created for `PowerMath.lib`.
15. To verify this, switch back from Property Manager to Solution Explorer (by clicking the Solution Explorer tab along the bottom of the sub-window). Go to Project Properties for your `SuperCalc.exe` project.  Go to "additional include directories".  Click on the down-arrow at the left side of that field and pick `Edit...`.  You will see that your property sheet settings are listed as "inherited values".
16. Sometimes the settings for a brand-new property sheet are not applied until you quit Visual Studio, re-start, and re-load the solution.  Remember to click **YES** when it asks whether you want to save your project changes and new property sheets!  Once it's all set up you shouldn't need to do this again.

Now any time you have a new project that uses `PowerMath.lib`, just go to the Property Manager and Add Existing Property Sheet: `PowerMath-settings.props`.

Remember that all changes made to the properties in the property sheet have to be made via the Property Manager dialog boxes, *not* using the `PowerMath.lib` Project Properties!  Project Properties is a kind of "override" property sheet that only applies to one specific project.  It stands above all the property sheets listed by the Property Manager.

Comment: What an amazing answer! Thank you so much.